# Open different modalboxes on links

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I have made a working [example on jsfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/0aubh5cj/). I am facing 2 problems.

**1:** I the example I have made 2 links inside a panel. Can it be true that the modalbox code is gonna fill so much inside the panel box? I need around 20 links in the modalbox, which would result in around 1200 rows. That would be quite a lot?

**2:** Each link should open a different modalbox, so I can change the text to match the link. How is that possible? I have to set an idea on the `modal class`, or is that totally wrong?

Best Regards

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="panel panel-primary">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h3 class="panel-title">GENERAL</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Cookie Policy</a><br/>
                        <!-- Cookie Policy Modal -->
                        <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
                            <div class="modal-dialog">
                                <!-- Modal content-->
                                <div class="modal-content">
                                    <div class="modal-header">
                                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                                        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="modal-body">
                                        <p>This is the text in the Cookie Policy modalbox</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="modal-footer">
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Opening hours</a><br/>
                        <!-- Cookie Policy Modal -->
                        <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
                            <div class="modal-dialog">
                              <!-- Modal content-->
                                <div class="modal-content">
                                    <div class="modal-header">
                                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                                        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="modal-body">
                                        <p>This is the text in the Opening modalbox</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="modal-footer">
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    $('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
        $('#myInput').focus()
    })
</script>
```